# what happens if neither res.send() nor res.end() is called in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a security issue that someone is trying to call random APIs that are not supported on our server but are frequently used for administrators API in general. and I set this code below to handle 404 to not respond to this attack

> url-not-found-handler.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function () {
  //4XX - URLs not found
  return ((req, res, next) => {
  });
};
```

what happens to client is that it waits until the server responds but I want to know if this will affect the performance of my express.js server also what happens behind the scene in the server without `res.send()` or `res.end()` ?

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation of [res.end()](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.end).

> Ends the response process. This method actually comes from Node core,
>   specifically the response.end() method of http.ServerResponse.

And then [response.end](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)

> This method signals to the server that all of the response headers and
>   body have been sent; that server should consider this message
>   complete. The method, response.end(), MUST be called on each response.

---

If you leave your request hanging, the `httpserver` will surely keep data about it. Which means that if you let hang many requests, your memory will grow and reduce your server performance.

About the client, he's going to have to wait until he got a request timeout.

---

The best to do having a bad request is to immediately reject the request, which is freeing the memory allowed for the request.

You cannot prevent bad requests (maybe have a firewall blocking requests from certains IP address?). Best you can do is to handle them as fast as possible.

Comment: So in short, memory leaks?

Comment: Memory leaks for sure. It could also have an other impact on the httpserver ; does the httpserver loop on each one of it's open requests to do things ? does the httpserver have a maximum number of opened requests ?

Well, when the documentation specify that you MUST do it, there is a good reason.

Comment: Not sure, since the official document doesn't mention what happens if you don't use `response.end()` I wrote a shell script with a loop iterating 10,000 times requesting random APIs to my server and i found my node.js process doesn't consume much memory.

Comment: @Daniel 10.000 isn't representative because it's quite few. Do this millions.

Comment: I did, but not much different. but still, I think it's better to use `response.end()` for clients

Comment: Is there a way to tell node to release resources without responding to client, though? I'd be rather happy to clog hacker's machine with hanging requests than to return him graceful responses.